SSL certificate for local network
For a winforms application that is ONLY used in the local network, we want to access some functions from the mobile phone (also connected locally).
In this case, a React+ .NET Core application hosted locally on IIS will be created.
The problem will be with the mobile browser that will ask for https/certificate and possibly a domain.
Can a solution be found?
thanks

Please define "we". Corporates have their own ways to set up internal CA for such scenarios. And if you mean just yourself, then solutions like Let's Encrypt are more than enough.

You can create your own certification authority
https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/creating-your-own-certificate-authority-server/
But you have to install the internal Root certificate on the mobile devices

Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.
